# Eclipse PHP Can't connect to SQL using XAMPP

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp

Can't connect to MySQL database. Error in Line 8 - Variable $conn is never used.

Hope someone can help me. I am a first time coder, and I get most of my tutorials from YouTube. I am using Eclipse as my IDE and XAMPP for my local server.

I am trying to create a dynamic website with login information so I am getting it connected to MySQL in XAMPP, but I keep getting an error in line 8 (yellow exclamation mark) where it says variable $conn is never used. The files are saved in htdocs so I don't think that's the issue.

When I try to run the code, I get an error message:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server.If you entered the URL manually please check yourspelling and try again. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.7
```

```
    <?php


    $dbServername = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbName = "login_information";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbpassword, $dbName);
```

Comment: `variable $conn is never used` is a warning, not an error. The editor says that you created the variable but never use it anywhere.

Comment: Which file you put your code in? Where do you place the code? and how did you run it?

Comment: I placed the code inside the htdocs folder then created another folder which I named "includes" so basically the path would be xampp\htdocs\PHPTest\includes. I run it using Eclipse. Tried it in browser as well and got the same error message. I also created another code called index in the htdocs folder itself in which I am trying to link to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

for dbusername, u used single quotes and for other variables, u used double kindly be symmetric use double quotes o else single and issue is you are typing the wrong path in URL xampp\htdocs\PHPTest\includes. it's wrong its just localhost/PHPTest/includes/index.php note here index.php vary according to the your file name and try again it will work.

before everything:
1 open xampp menu start apache and MySQL make sure they are running properly

2 in eclipse change the default browser to Chrome or Mozilla whichever u use

3 and code should be extended further do some DB operations and say mysqli_query($conn,$sql); note $sql is a variable where you store SQL operation like select delete edit anything after this line 8 error disappear you just declared variable but never used so.

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered! You're suggestions helped me find the answer. It looks like when I tried to run the site the location show http://localhost/PHPTest/dbh.inc.php thus shows the error, but when I added the includes folder in the path (http://localhost/PHPTest/includes/dbh.inc.php). The site somewhat works (need to create the homepage first). Greatly value all of your feedback!